# Duplicate input without freezing catcodes

Tags: tex-core, catcodes

Background:

I am currently writing a document in which I want to typeset some sentences in braille (using the `braille` package) as well as in normal text. My first attempt was to just say `\def\foo{This is an example sentence.}` and later print it with `\foo` and `\expandafter\braille\expandafter{\foo}`. However, this did not work (at least not properly: there were no linebreaks in the braille sentence), because `\braille` changes some catcodes.

After looking up the definition of `\braille`

```
\def\braille{\begingroup\catcode`\ =12\catcode`\^^M=12\let\brl@@spc\undefined\@braille}
```

I was able to create the following command:

```
\def\defbrailletext{%
    \begingroup\let\@braille\relax\braille%
        \@defbrailletext%
}
\def\@defbrailletext#1#2{%
        \def#1{{\raggedright\noindent\braille{#2}\par}}%
    \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\endgroup%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}%
}
```

With this, I can say `\defbrailletext\foo{This is an example sentence.}` and later print the sentence in braille using `\foo`. However, I do not have access to the sentence with the usual catcodes.

Ideally, I would like to have `\defbrailletext` create two macros (say, `\foo` and `\braillefoo`) that contain the normal text (with normal catcodes) and the braille text respectively. It seems to me that this requires me to duplicate `This is an example sentence.` without "freezing" its catcodes, which means macros are out of the question. Can this be done in TeX? If yes, how?

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{braille}

\makeatletter
    \def\defbrailletext{%
        \begingroup\let\@braille\relax\braille%
            \@defbrailletext%
    }
    \def\@defbrailletext#1#2{%
            \def#1{{\raggedright\noindent\braille{#2}\par}}%
        \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\endgroup%
        \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% I can do this:
\def\foo{This is a test sentence.}
\foo

% And I can do this:
\defbrailletext\foo{This is a test sentence.}
\foo

% How can I do both at the same time?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal compilable example?

Comment: Of course, @egreg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to avoid freezing the catcodes, but you can "unfreeze" them with `\scantokens`. It might be best to read with braille catcodes first because otherwise some spaces might be lost before they can be unfreezed.
This can be done with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braille}
\makeatletter
\def\defbrailletext#1{%
  \begingroup\let\@braille\relax\braille%
  \@defbrailletext#1%
}
\def\@defbrailletext#1#2{%
  \endgroup
  \endgroup
  \scantokens{\def#1{#2}\ignorespaces}% A \scantokens trick from David Carlisle
  \expandafter\def\csname braille\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\endcsname{{\raggedright\noindent\braille{#2}\par}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\defbrailletext\foo{some thing}
\braillefoo
\foo
\end{document}
```

[image]